# How to search for documents based on the value of adding 2 properties on the document?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document:

```
{"price1": 500, "price2": 500}
```

I want to find all documents where "(price1 + price 2) < 1200".  I assume I can do this by using the aggregation framework, but not seeing the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [$add](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/). Try the following code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $project: { total: { $add: [ "$price1", "$price2" ] } } }, 
    { $match: {total: {$lt: 1200  }} }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator to return all documents where the sum of "price1" and "price2" greater than `1200`. Of course to get the sum you need to use the [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) operator.The [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)operator evaluates and returns the documents that if that expression is `true` using the [`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep) variable and exclude all documents where that condition evaluates to false using the [`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) variable.

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$lt": [ 
                { "$add": [ "$price1", "$price2"] },
                1200
            ]},
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}
])
```